# Pandas - Finding Duplicate value of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements, data-analysis

I was looking for two different methods to find a duplicate value of a column in a df.

First to find if a value in a column based on a condtion of a different column exsits in a different df. If in df_1 any id with the same times in the time column exists in df_2

such as

df_1

```
id |       time  
ab23 2019-04-17 01:00:00
bv63 2019-04-16 22:00:00
```

df_2

```
id |     time  
ab23 2019-04-17 01:00:00
bv63 2019-04-16 22:00:00
```

also to check if the same id exists in the same column in the same df regardless of any other col. So to see if in df_1 any id has any duplicates in the same df.

I am trying to see if the ids have duplicates in the same df and also based on the condtion that they have the same id and time in the different dfs.

Answer (score 1):

Set up example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['a','a','c'],
    'time':[pd.Timestamp('2019-04-17 01:00:00'),
            pd.Timestamp('2019-04-18 22:00:00'),
            pd.Timestamp('2019-04-16 22:00:00')]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['e','f'],
    'time':[pd.Timestamp('2019-04-17 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-04-02 22:00:00')]
})
```

> check if the same id exists in the same column in the same df regardless of any other col.

```
dupes = df1['id'].duplicated()
df1['id'][dupes]
```

> If in df_1 any id with the same times in the time column exists in df_2

```
matches = df1['time'].isin(df2['time'])
df1['id'][matches]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the index data. Convert the contents of the data frames to sets of tuples containing the columns:

```
ds1 = set([tuple(line) for line in df1.values])
ds2 = set([tuple(line) for line in df2.values])
```

This step will get rid of any duplicates in the data frames as well (index ignored)

```
set([(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3)])   # ds1
```

can then use set methods to find anything. Eg to find differences:

```
ds1.difference(ds2)
gives: set([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```

can take that back to dataframe if needed. Note have to transform set to list 1st as set cannot be used to construct dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(ds1.difference(ds2)))
```